# How to map characters to integer range [-128, 127] in Python?

Tags: python, range, modulo, negative-number

I would like to convert a list of characters (represented on a single byte ie. the range [0, 255]) to be represented with integers in the range [-128,127]. I've read that Python's modulo operator (`%`) always return a number having the same sign as the denominator.

What is the right way to do this conversion in Python?

**EDIT**
Characters that map to [128,255] with `ord` should be remapped to [-128,-1], with 128 mapped to -128 and 255 mapped to -1. (For the inverse of the conversion I use `chr(my_int%256)`, but `my_int` can be a negative number.)

Comment: I think we'll need a bit more info to understand what you are trying to do.  What is your input set of characters?  Are there 256 total characters?  Do they have contiguous ordinals?

Comment: @sberry I edited my question to better reflect what I mean.

Comment: when is the output number positive?

Comment: @christophe31 if the `ord` of the input char is in the range [0,127] then the output is a positive number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found out that I could do this conversion with "[unpack](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack)ing from [byte](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters)" with the [struct](http://pymotw.com/2/struct/) module:

```
# gotcha|pitfall: my original idea, but this generates a list of 1-tuples:
# x = [struct.unpack("b",a) for a in charlist]

fmt = "%ib"%len(charlist) # eg. "5b", if charlist's length is 5
x = struct.unpack(fmt,charlist) # tuple of ints
```

Comment: Ah, very nice solution, signed char for the win.

Comment: You should accept your own answer, because it is the best solution IMO.

Comment: @sberry thanks; I wanted to wait but then I think I will do so, however SO asks me to wait for 2 days before I can accept my own answer.

Comment: @christophe31 struct.unpack gives 2.1 compared the solutions in your and sberry's answer, both giving around 17. these are mapping slightly differently. duskas's gives ~ 14 and maps more differently.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood the question... You want to do something like that?

```
[i - 255 if i > 127 else i for i in [ord(l) for l in "azertyuiopqsdféhjklm3{"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def to_ints(input):
    return [o if o <= 128 else 255 - o for o in [ord(char) in input]]

def to_str(input):
    return "".join([chr(i%256) for i in input])

out = to_ints("This is a test")
print to_str(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what do you mean by "a list of characters", are they numbers? If so, I think `x % 256 - 128` or `x % -256 + 128` should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but for future readers the straightforward solution for single integers is `(x + 128)%256 - 128`.  Replace `x` with `ord(c)` if dealing with ASCII character data.

The result of the `%` operator there is congruent (mod 256) to `x + 128`; and subtracting 128 from that makes the final result congruent to `x` *and* shifts the range to [128,127].

This will work in a generator expression, and save a step in Python 3 where you'd need to convert a string to a `bytes` object.